# Get primary key for a ModelChoiceField based on his "id" in the form

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using a Django form wich contains a ModelChoiceField.

In my form I want to update a part of the form with Ajax when the user change the value in the `<select>`

I pass to my ajax view the id of the option selected, but I would like to know how can I retrieve from this `id` the `pk` associated in my DB.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I think the selected option value and the pk are the same.

Comment: Ho yes you are right! Thanks. If you put an answer instead of a comment I can mark it as the solution ;)